# Linux Bash autonumbering of filenames without removing leading zero

Tags: linux, bash, counter

With Linux I'd like to automatically add Oracle DB tablespaces within the used format. To do this, I'd like to do an increment of +1 compared to the previous file.

The data files are typically called with this format:

```
/ora/oradata/tablespace_datafile.dbf
/ora/oradata/tablespace_datafile_02.dbf
/ora/oradata/tablespace_datafile_3.dbf
```

I was able to extract the `$basefilename` to a variable with `sed 's/[0-9].*//`, which gives as output: `/ora/oradata/tablespace_datafile_`

I was also able to extract the numbers with `sed s/[^0-9]//g` to the variable which supposed to be the `$counter`, this gives as output for the above examples: `02` and `3` respectively.

I am, however, having difficulties to add +1 to the `$counter`, without removing the leading zero (`02` should be next `03`, but instead, I get `3`. I am using `let counter++`.

**Current code:**

```
basefilename=`echo $connectdb | sed 's/[0-9].*//'`
counter=`echo $connectdb | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'`
let counter++
nextdatafilename=$basefilename$counter'.dbf'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: And what should follow `09`? `10` or `010`?

Comment: Use `$basefilename$( prinf "%02d" $counter )'.dbf`'  `2` in  `%02d` should be replaced with the real desired number

Comment: Hi, yes, 10 should follow 09.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bash function will increment its numeric argument preserving the leading zeros as required (note that syntax highlighting is confused by the `${parameter##word}` parameter expansion syntax):

```
inc() ( shopt -s extglob; printf "%0${#1}d" $((${1##+(0)} + 1)) )
```

Examples:

```
$ echo $(inc 1)
2
$ echo $(inc 01)
02
$ echo $(inc 001)
002
$ echo $(inc 09)
10
$ echo $(inc 009)
010
$ echo $(inc 0)
1
```

Using it for your situation:

```
nextdatafilename="$basefilename$(inc $counter).dbf"
```

Explanation:

- `printf "%0${#1}d"` formats the result using at least as many digits as the argument contains
- `shopt -s extglob` enables extended pattern matching so that expanding `${1##+(0)}` removes *all* leading zeros (this is necessary, since a number prefixed with a zero is interpreted by bash as octal).
- the function body is enclosed in parentheses rather than braces so that the effect of `shopt -s extglob` is local to the function invocation and doesn't affect the caller's environment.

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you. I have seen and know some functions, but never seen something looking like this before.

Comment: This function, however, does stop at 100.

Comment: @IvanM What do you mean by that?

Comment: Oh never mind, my query on the back is giving the wrong MAX value :)

Answer (score 2):

With `perl` based `rename` command

```
rename -n 's/0*\K\d+(?=\.dbf)/$&+1/e' *.dbf
```

- `0*\K` ignore leading zeros
- `\d+` match digits
- `(?=\.dbf)` assumes numbers end with filename extension as mentioned in OP, this ensures that numbers are not matched anywhere else. Can be removed if not needed
- `$&+1` add one to matched digits
- `/e` this modifier allows to use expression instead of string in replacement section

The `-n` option to `rename` command allows to run a dry test before actual renaming

Sample test

```
$ rename -n 's/0*\K\d+(?=\.dbf)/$&+1/e' tst/*.dbf
rename(tst/abc_01.dbf, tst/abc_02.dbf)
rename(tst/aef_2.dbf, tst/aef_3.dbf)
```

If `09` has to be changed to `10` instead of `010`:

```
$ rename -n 's/\d+(?=\.dbf)/sprintf "%02d", $&+1/e' tst/*.dbf
rename(tst/abc_01.dbf, tst/abc_02.dbf)
rename(tst/aef_09.dbf, tst/aef_10.dbf)
```

Change `%02d` to `%03d` for three digit formatting and so on...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
nextdatafilename=$( printf "%s%02d.dbf" $basefilename $counter )
```